# Trouble working with activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

**Source at bottom**

I am working with a program called "GameMaker:Studio" and I am currently writing a java extension for it for an Android application. I've solved a few other things with research, but now I'm at a true road block. 
**My Problem** is that now that I actually have my GoogleApiClient instance to be created and *kind of* work, I can't access its callbacks.

**class setup:**

```
public class PlayerConnect extends Activity
implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
RealTimeMessageReceivedListener,
RoomStatusUpdateListener, RoomUpdateListener, OnInvitationReceivedListener{
```

*important* **imports**:

```
// YYg ** These imports are here to make my class more functional
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.R;
import ${YYAndroidPackageName}.RunnerActivity;
import com.yoyogames.runner.RunnerJNILib;
// Including
com.google.android.gms.common. --- all the used ones
com.google.android.gms.games. -- all the used ones
```

As you can see it inherits from class and then implements the interfaces that are used by Google's client class. It imports all the correct imports.

Once I actually **create my Client** like so,

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .build();
```

I can work with it (slightly). The problem is that although it is functional, the activity belongs to `RunnerActivity` **not** *my* class `PlayerConnect`. This causes problems because since now that my class can't personally handle the callbacks that I have setup, the `RunnerActivity` will, and ends up crashing because it doesn't understand. And besides crashing, I can't make my program react to connections or failures.

Is there anyway I can workaround this? If I try using **this** as the context in the clients Builder, then the client never gets created. I think it has something to do with my activity never actually being created, but I think there's nothing I can do about that because I've tried copying bundles and sharing intents/the such but nothing like that works.

**What I'm hoping to be able to do** is somehow defer the clients callbacks to my classes' functions since that is the only feasible thing for me to accomplish. Is there anyway I can redirect to my functions? Or the like?

I've read somethings about threading that may be able to create a workaround but I haven't gotten it to work, just crash. Something like a viewhandler?

```
RunnerActivity.ViewHandler.post( new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        onCreate(RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity.getIntent().extras());
        onStart();
      }
    });
```

#### Java Source

Comment: You are trying to prevent the `Activity` from calling `onCreate` and `onStart`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows thanks for responding, I appreciate it. What I'm trying to do is make the callbacks used in the handlers I set `addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)` inside the GoogleApiClient to work with my class, `PlayerConnect` which extends activity, and not the `RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity`.

Comment: Post your `Activity`, are you actually implementing those interfaces?

Comment: My activity is in the post under **Class Setup**, what's happening is that the activity I don't have access too `RunnerActivity.CurrentActivity` takes over

Comment: You have to post all the code. Its hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay, it is very messy, but I'll post it as a link

Comment: First thing by looking at your source: Don't comment your imports and you need to format your code. I see you have implemented the callbacks: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html. What is your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73042/discussion-between-lemony-andrew-and-jared-burrows).

Comment: hi, @author.  Can you help me solve this embedding webview to gm screen http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/96229-tearing-me-hair-out-trying-solve-webview-embedding.html#post413458